# creating Pipeline for text classification with XGBoost using Tf-idf

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, xgboost, tf-idf

I am currently working on text classification. I have converted the text to vector using TF-idf. I have two columns '`Description`' as independent and '`label`' as target variable. Below is my code:

```
X,y = data.drop(['label'],axis=1),data['label']

docs = list(X['Description'])

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_vec = tfidf.fit_transform(docs)

docs = tfidf_vec.to_array()

clf = XGBClassifier().fit(docs,y)
```

The above code is working perfectly fine.
I want to create a pipeline for the above steps.I did the following but getting error:

```
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('tfidf' ,TfidfVectorizer()), 
                   ('model',XGBClassifier())])
```

However this is giving me error as :

```
    training_pipeling.fit(X, y)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py39_v2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:1151 in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py39_v2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:415 in fit
    fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py39_v2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:331 in _check_fit_params
    fit_params_steps = {name: {} for name, step in self.steps if step is not None}

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py39_v2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:331 in <dictcomp>
    fit_params_steps = {name: {} for name, step in self.steps if step is not None}

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please (always) provide the full error traceback.

Comment: @BenReiniger - Updated error message

Comment: The error message looks like the pipeline steps aren't all 2-tuples as they're supposed to be, but your pipeline definition looks fine. I do notice your code calls it `pipe` but the error is from `training_pipeling`; can you double-check and fix that mismatch?